# Can't connect to noVNC server

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

I have used git to get the noVNC repository from [github](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC).
I started server with `./utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901`. After that I typed url (received in my console) in browser.

http://user.local:6080/vnc.html?host=user.local&port=6080 (I have replaced actual user name).

But when I visit this url and enter user.local and port 6080 I get:

```
 27: 10.1.0.164: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
 27: 10.1.0.164: Version hybi-13, base64: 'False'
 27: 10.1.0.164: Path: '/websockify'
 27: connecting to: localhost:5901
 27: handler exception: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Should I start something else?

Comment: looks like the vnc server isn't running (or at least not on localhost) - probably work looking for the vnc process / any logs / nmapping the port, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to generate a certificate for connecting a websocket: https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/wiki/Encrypted-Connections